# How to detect Android application package from PHP?

Tags: php, android, http

It is possible to detect Android application from php ? I make a HTTP request from android application to PHP script, can I detect in php application package (ex. com.exampleapp.rew), I need this to do a filter between applications that request to the server.

Comment: for that u have to pass package name to server and store into database.

Comment: this is not secure, another applications can pass the same package to the server and results that have access

Comment: package name is publicly available when you upload your application to market :P

Comment: You need to send some type of cryptographic hash in the header based on the package name, the time/date and a salt. So another App can't simply spoof it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The apps have to send their package names by their own.

You should encrypt the packages names, so other applications can't send self-defined package names.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still searching for the same queries, then try this:

```
$package_or_bundle = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ?? null;
echo $package_or_bundle;
```